# como puedo hacer que funcione bien mi DB::Select en laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Buen día, colegas programadores tengo un problema que no entiendo el por qué, tengo el siguiente query:

```php
$cuotas = DB::select('select fecha, if(cantidad>0, cantidad + cantidad * porcentaje,cantidad) cantidad, round(if(cantidad>0, @saldo:= cantidad + cantidad * porcentaje, @saldo:=@saldo + cantidad),2) saldo from credito where id_cliente='.$id_cliente.' and id>=(select max(id) id from (SELECT * FROM credito where cantidad>0 and id_cliente='.$id_cliente.') a)');
```

y me muestra esto (esto está bien):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al hacer este query:

```php
$cuotas = DB::select('select fecha, cantidad, saldo from (select fecha, if(cantidad>0, cantidad + cantidad * porcentaje,cantidad) cantidad, round(if(cantidad>0, @saldo:= cantidad + cantidad * porcentaje, @saldo:=@saldo + cantidad),2) saldo from credito where id_cliente='.$id_cliente.' and id>=(select max(id) id from (SELECT * FROM credito where cantidad>0 and id_cliente='.$id_cliente.') a) order by fecha desc limit 5 ) a order by fecha asc');
```

y muestra esto que no me muestra el saldo, sino que lo muestra null (esto está mal):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si yo hago ese query en mi Gestor de BD todo está bien porque me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensando en la solución se me ocurren varias cosas.
1- Como puedo hacer para que el query me funcione y no me dé nulo.
2- Como puedo hacer para que aunque ponga todo el resultado en el foreach ó html me muestre únicamente las últimas 5 filas por ejemplo.

PD: ya hice varias pruebas y me he dado cuenta de que cuando agrego "Order by" ya me empieza a mostrar el null en el saldo, específicamente cuando le coloco el DESC, ya que si se deja como esta o se le coloca ASC no hay ningún problema

Comment: Una primera sugerencia: utiliza [*consultas preparadas*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) ***siempre***

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo que pasa es que no siempre puedo sacar el resultado deseado y la verdad se me hace muy fácil realizar mis consultas en un SGBD, pero es la primera vez que me pasa esto.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que uno de los valores dinámicos que utilizas, no es correcto. Verifica que las variables que estás concatenando en tu consulta tengan el valor esperado. Haz la prueba escribiendo la consulta que haces en tu SGBD, sin concatenarle ninguna variable, es decir has un *hardcode*, y verifica el resultado.